# RuntimeException: preferences has not been initialised

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I searched among many similar SharedPreferences questions, but couldn't apply to my project.
It's a RuntimeException which requires a SharedPreferences lateinit variable to be initialised.

Error Message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.tabuild3/com.me.tabuild3.Tutorial}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mPref has not been initialized

(...)

Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mPreferences has not been initialized
    at com.me.tabuild3.Z3Preferences.<init>(Z3Preferences.kt:15)
    at com.me.tabuild3.Tutorial.onCreate(Tutorial.kt:15)
```

This is Tutorial.kt, which triggers the error:

```
class Tutorial : AppCompatActivity() {
   val binding by lazy {
       B00TutorialBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
   }
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.b00_tutorial)
       
       val fragmentList = listOf(Z0A(), Z1B(), Z3Preferences()) // the 15th line is here
       val adapter = Z99FragmentAdapter(this)
       adapter.fragmentList = fragmentList

       binding.tutorialPager.adapter = adapter
       binding.tutorialPager.currentItem = 1
   }
}
```

This activity loads three fragments, and the third one, Z3Preferences(), edits SharedPreferences to modify things(At least I plan so).

This is Z3Preferences, which holds actual(?) error:

```
class Z3Preferences : Fragment() {
   lateinit var binding: F04PrefBinding
   private lateinit var mPref: SharedPreferences // seems this thing has to be initialised
   val preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor = mPref.edit() // same error message for this line when the upper solved(?)

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       binding = F04PrefBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       return binding.root
   }

   override fun onResume() {
       super.onResume()
       binding.radioGroupTextSize.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        when (checkedId) {
            R.id.textSize_RB1 -> preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSZ", 12)
            R.id.textSize_RB2 -> preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSZ", 14)
            R.id.textSize_RB3 -> preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSZ", 16)
            R.id.textSize_RB4 -> preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSZ", 18)
            R.id.textSize_RB5 -> preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSZ", 20)
        }
    }
    binding.radioGroupTextSpeed.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        when (checkedId) {
               R.id.textSpd_RB1 -> {
                   preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSP", 160)
                   preferencesEditor.putBoolean("TXTAN", true)
               }
               R.id.textSpd_RB2 -> {
                   preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSP", 120)
                   preferencesEditor.putBoolean("TXTAN", true)
               }
               R.id.textSpd_RB3 -> {
                   preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSP", 80)
                   preferencesEditor.putBoolean("TXTAN", true)
               }
               R.id.textSpd_RB4 -> {
                   preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSP", 40)
                   preferencesEditor.putBoolean("TXTAN", true)
               }
               R.id.textSpd_RB5 -> {
                   preferencesEditor.putInt("TXTSP", 40)
                   preferencesEditor.putBoolean("TXTAN", false)
               }
           }
       }
   }

   override fun onPause() {
       super.onPause()
       preferencesEditor.apply()
   }
}
```

So.. How do I initialise the lateinit var mPref? I'm totally lost at this point and similar questions have different app construction and I couldn't get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So.. How do I initialise the lateinit var mPref?

You set it  to some valid value, usually as early as possible. On Android, this usually means doing so in `onCreate` or `onCreateView`. But at least before anything tries to access it. You can do this in your `onCreateView`:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   mPref = // get preferences in your prefered way
   binding = F04PrefBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
   return binding.root
}
```

> it shoots the same error for the next line(I marked on the code in the post): "lateinit property mPref has not been initialized", but at the next line! How do I do this?

You are trying to use an unintialized `lateinit` variable immediately after declaring it:

```
private lateinit var mPref: SharedPreferences // Declared but not initialized
val preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor = mPref.edit() // Immediately attemps to use mPref which is not initialized (during constructor call)
```

You need to not try to initialize the editor immediately like that.

You can either make it a property, so it only tries to access mPref when accessed and *not* during constructor call, which assumes it'll be valid by the time you try to access the editor:

```
val preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor get() = mPref.edit()
```

Or, you could make the editor itself a `lateinit` property and initialize it later:

```
lateinit var preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
   mPref = // get preferences in your prefered way
   preferencesEditor = mPref.edit()
   binding = F04PrefBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
   return binding.root
}
```

Please check the documentation for how [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) and kotlin [constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) work.

Comment: Thank you sir you're a saint! Now I found loads of similar problems and I say I can handle it. I'll check those documentations too!

Answer (score 2):

you need the context to init the sharedPreferences.
You can do that like this:

mPref = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

I would do this in the onCreate method of the fragment.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mPref = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences("pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        //other initializations ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Again it shoots the same error for the next line(I marked on the code in the post): "lateinit property mPref has not been initialized", but at the next line! How do I do this?

Comment: The other answer solved it but yours was also relly helpful. Thanks a lot!